# Ecto: Create new row based on existing row

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm try to copy a postgres row with changes. `link` is the existing row. I've tried various permutations but cannot create the changeset - would welcome help.

I'm using this version of ecto

```
:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0-rc"`
```

and this code

```
        IO.inspect(link)
        changeset =
            link
            |> Map.from_struct
            # |> Map.delete(:id)
            |> Upload.persist_changeset(params)
        # new_link =
        #     Map.put link, :file_names, params["file_names"]
        # case Repo.insert new_link do
        case Repo.insert changeset do
            {:ok, link} ->
                render conn, "link.json", link: link.link
            {:error, changeset} ->
                ...
        end
```

and

```
  def persist_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(upload_type file_names), ~w(job_id template_id estimate_ids))
  end
```

IO.inspect

```
%Api.Upload{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "uploads">,
 email: "hotbelgo@gmail.com", estimate_ids: [1],
 file_names: ["f1.pdf", "f2.pdf"], id: 8,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-04 10:01:21>,
 job: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :job is not loaded>, job_id: 1,
 link: "na2ClfJie4PsYC4y8Lr9",
 template: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :template is not loaded>,
 template_id: nil, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-04 14:21:58>,
 upload_type: "Artwork"}
```

Error

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/4

And this is the scheme for `link`

```
defmodule MosaicApi.Upload do
  use MosaicApi.Web, :model

  schema "uploads" do
    belongs_to :job, MosaicApi.Job
    belongs_to :template, MosaicApi.Template
    field :estimate_ids, {:array, :integer}

    field :upload_type, :string
    field :file_names, {:array, :string}

    field :link, :string
    field :email, :string

    timestamps
  end
```

Comment: Does this work: `changeset = Upload.persist_changeset(%{link | id: nil}, params)`?

Comment: Now I get: `Please preload your associations before casting or changing the struct`. I understand this message don't really want to preload the `job` as I just want to keep the `job_id`

Comment: Could you please include the output of `IO.inspect(link)` in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, although I'm not sure it is the best approach

```
        update_params =
            link
            |> Map.from_struct
            |> Map.put :file_names, params["file_names"]
            changeset =
                Upload.changeset(%Upload{}, update_params)
```

Comment: Is `file_names` the only field you want from `params`?

Comment: Yes. Basically the record contains a unique, non-guessable links and some other ids. It supports weblinks shared with third parties to enable them to upload files to my site. I want to allow the links to be reused, but to store the names of the files uploaded each time, hence the copying of the existing data but changing :file_names